# How to use a jQuery file from other HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page in that, I included a `test.js` file. On click of a button, I am opening a pop up. And that will be the second `HTML` page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" scr ="test.js">
```

Now, I want to use `test.js` for all the logic's and I don't want to include again this `test.js` in the pop.html. Please suggest me how can we do this.

Comment: why ??see the issue is again i don't have to include the js file in the pop html so can i use this js file

Comment: Refer to the following link on StackOverflow containing solutions:

[Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: if the pop up is not a new window then , no need to include the js file again ,you will call the function in the js file

Comment: @Neil I didn't insult your mother tongue language.. read my comment again. I am saying most of the users here don't know Hindi language. should they use google translate or what? btw, "area51" is a place where you can propose new sites. (I think this is the word which made you confused).

Comment: If pop.html is loaded in a new document context (new page), you will have to include test.js again to have it available there. Where is the actual problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is kind of inheritance in the templates. As far as I know this is possible in Django.

If you want to implement this using jQuery, instead of opening a second.html load it in an div.

For e.g.

`$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});`

If you do this test.js wont have to be included again and again.

Answer (score 1):

you can load all resources needed by pages on the first page, and extract body content of the html result returned by ajax calls.

```
$.get('/handler.html', function(result) {
    $('#pageContainer').html($(result).find('body').html());
});
```